# How can I smooth out my textured bathtub?

Tags: bathroom

We have a textured bath-tub, we *want* to remove the texture (because it's fading and it's easy to slip on, but because of the texture bath mats don't stay on). We're considering re-glazing it, and are wondering if that will work, or if there are any others ways to remove the texture.

Comment: This question can be answered with either "yes" or "no". As a longtime member of this community, I'd suggest changing it to something like, "How can I smooth out my textured bathtub?" You can say in the body of the question that you are consider re-glazing it, but community members might offer you some simpler solutions and ideas you hadn't thought of!

Comment: You could try sanding it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can think of 3 solutions, none of them is really perfect.

1. Buy new bathtub without texture. No comments, everything should be clear.
2. Re-glaze it (as you already mentioned). Results are better if operation is done by an experienced person.
3. Un-texture it. Actually, this is polishing it to an acceptable level.

For number 3, it may or it may not work. First condition: how thick is the current texture. Does it allow for some polishing (to the level desired)? If no, then that's it, option 3 is out of question.

If yes, the same polishing procedure as used for cars can be used. I cannot think of a reason why a car-polish procedure would not work for the bathtub. Again, someone with experience may produce a better result.